# Ошибка при создании dns зоны

Tags: dns

При вводе команды named-checkzone e-gov-kz.ru /var/named/e-gov-kz.ru.zone, выдает ошибку:  failed: file not found
zone e-gov-kz.ru/IN: not loaded due to errors.

```html
$TTL 86400
@       IN SOA ns1.e-gov-kz.ru. ns2.e-gov-kz.ru. (
        2017011301   ;serial
        3600         ;refresh
        1800         ;retry
        604800       ;expire
        86400       ;minimum TTL
)
  
        IN           NS     ns1.e-gov-kz.ru.
        IN           NS     ns2.e-gov-kz.ru.
        IN           MX     10    mail.e-gov-kz.ru.

@       IN            A          185.209.20.21
ns1     IN            A          185.209.20.21
ns2     IN            A          185.209.20.21
mail    IN            A          185.209.20.21
www   IN          A        185.209.20.21
```

Comment: `file not found` говорит о том, что утилита не смогла найти файл. его содержимое тут не причем. Убедитесь что файл лежит именно там, с учетом текущего корня

Comment: Как раз таки все в нужной директории лежит

Comment: Файл e-gov-kz.zone находится в /var/named

Comment: Да, но вы же пишите в команде e-gov-kz.ru.zone

Comment: Это команда проверяет наличие ошибок, но почему то она не может найти файл.

Comment: Для начала определитесь, как у вас называется файл e-gov-kz.ru.zone или e-gov-kz.zone А то вы путаетесь в показаниях ... Вот я бы то же не нашел файл /var/named/e-gov-kz.zone, если бы искал /var/named/e-gov-kz.ru.zone ...

Comment: лучше всего явно перейдите в каталог где лежит файл и от туда вызовите команду не указывая пути, что бы она брала из текущего каталога. При этом используйте автодополнение имени (в bash клавиша Tab)

Comment: В том то и дело, даже автодополнение не работает на этом файле, что очень странно

Comment: но при этом его содержимое вы с помощью cat выводите ?

Comment: Я редактировал его через sftp client

Comment: ну попробуйте все таки командой cat его вывести, что бы убедится что он читается. И может sftp на него какие нибудь странные права поставил

Comment: При вводе в консоле ls, этого файла вообще не видно, что очень странно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, оказывается я перепутал данные одного сервера с другим, и заливал файлы на другой сервер